# Specifying RabbitMQ messaging strategy on memeory or disc

Tags: rabbitmq

I am new at RabbitMQ am wonder something about saving message strategy. By default RabbitMQ saves message queuses on memeory. This way is high performance. But messages are important and should be save on disc. Because server may down at any time. This way shows slower performace. 
Which stuation should be prefable. What is your real world experience?

Answer (score 0):

There is a whole lot regarding persistance [here](https://www.rabbitmq.com/persistence-conf.html).
You can make queues durable, in that way messages are saved to the disk. Of course only until they are acknowledged!

You didn't say what is your use case and what do you need this for, but bare in mind that RAbbitMQ is not a database.